# How could I implement an early return from outside the body of a method in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-inference, continuations, control-flow

*Disclaimer:* Before someone says it: yes, I know it's bad style and not encouraged. I'm just doing this to play with Scala and try to learn more about how the type inference system works and how to tweak control flow. I don't intend to use this code in practice.

---

So: suppose I'm in a rather lengthy function, with lots of successive checks at the beginning, which, if they fail, are all supposed to cause the function to return some other value (not throw), and otherwise return the normal value. I cannot use `return` in the body of a `Function`. But can I simulate it? A bit like `break` is simulated in `scala.util.control.Breaks`?

I have come up with this:

```
object TestMain {

  case class EarlyReturnThrowable[T](val thrower: EarlyReturn[T], val value: T) extends ControlThrowable
  class EarlyReturn[T] {
    def earlyReturn(value: T): Nothing = throw new EarlyReturnThrowable[T](this, value)
  }

  def withEarlyReturn[U](work: EarlyReturn[U] => U): U = {
    val myThrower = new EarlyReturn[U]
    try work(myThrower)
    catch {
      case EarlyReturnThrowable(`myThrower`, value) => value.asInstanceOf[U]
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val g = withEarlyReturn[Int] { block =>
      if (!someCondition)
        block.earlyReturn(4)

      val foo = precomputeSomething
      if (!someOtherCondition(foo))
        block.earlyReturn(5)

      val bar = normalize(foo)
      if (!checkBar(bar))
        block.earlyReturn(6)

      val baz = bazify(bar)
      if (!baz.isOK)
        block.earlyReturn(7)

      // now the actual, interesting part of the computation happens here
      // and I would like to keep it non-nested as it is here
      foo + bar + baz + 42 // just a dummy here, but in practice this is longer
    }
    println(g)
  }
}
```

My checks here are obviously dummy, but the main point is that I'd like to avoid something like this, where the actually interesting code ends up being way too nested for my taste:

```
if (!someCondition) 4 else {
  val foo = precomputeSomething
  if (!someOtherCondition(foo)) 5 else {
    val bar = normalize(foo)
    if (!checkBar(bar)) 6 else {
      val baz = bazify(bar)
      if (!baz.isOK) 7 else {
        // actual computation
        foo + bar + baz + 42 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My solution works fine here, and I can return early with 4 as return value if I want. Trouble is, I *have* to explicitly write the type parameter `[Int]` — which is a bit of a pain. Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: I don't think it's _always_ bad practice.  It does seem to be overused in languages that make it easy and don't provide good alternatives.

Comment: If you write your case distinction in the shallow way (using `else if`), your "actual computation" is only nested once compared to not nested in your hack. What is the problem with that? In your example, all you save is one keyword `else` but you have all the overhead.

Comment: @Raphael Yes *in that example*, but I've specified that I'm looking at cases where, of course, I have more than one condition to check — usually 3 or 4, so my actual code would be nested 3 or 4 times.

Comment: You can always get rid of that nesting (by copying some conditions), but I guess you do not want that? Anyway, your call to earlyReturn has to be nested, right? So what do you really expect to save but the nesting around "actual computation"?

Comment: @Raphael I think we keep missing each other's point here, so I've edited my example. The call to `earlyReturn` is maybe nested, but doesn't need braces and could be on the same line. My final computation's nesting level should not depend on the number of checked conditions before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unrelated to your main question, but I think, a more effective approach (that doesn't require throwing an exception) to implement `return` would involve continuations:

```
def earlyReturn[T](ret: T): Any @cpsParam[Any, Any] = shift((k: Any => Any) => ret)
def withEarlyReturn[T](f: => T @cpsParam[T, T]): T = reset(f)
def cpsunit: Unit @cps[Any] = ()

def compute(bool: Boolean) = { 
    val g = withEarlyReturn {
         val a = 1
         if(bool) earlyReturn(4) else cpsunit    
         val b = 1
         earlyReturn2(4, bool)            
         val c = 1
         if(bool) earlyReturn(4) else cpsunit            
         a + b + c + 42
    }
    println(g)  
}
```

The only problem here, is that you have to explicitly use `cpsunit`.

**EDIT1:** Yes, `earlyReturn(4, cond = !checkOK)` can be implemented, but it won't be that general and elegant:

```
def earlyReturn2[T](ret: T, cond: => Boolean): Any @cpsParam[Any, Any] =
                            shift((k: Any => Any) => if(cond) ret else k())
```

`k` in the snippet above represents the rest of the computation. Depending on the value of `cond`, we either return the value, or continue the computation.

**EDIT2:** `Any chance we might get rid of cpsunit?` The problem here is that `shift` inside the `if` statement is not allowed without `else`. The compiler refuses to convert `Unit` to `Unit @cps[Unit]`.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting approach. Would you care to add some more explanations for those of us that are not familiar with continuations?

Comment: Any chance we might get rid of `cpsunit` if we allow a call like `earlyReturn(4, cond = !checkOK)`, moving the condition to a boolean param? Or would you have something more elegant in mind? Lastly: does the approach with continuations still work if several of them are nested?

Comment: >> "does the approach with continuations still work if several of them are nested?" With some edits, yes, it does.

Comment: As no other answer was provided on how to get rid of my type annotation, I'll assume I just have to write it and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think a custom exception is the right instinct here.